# Naming/referring joined tables

Tags: sql, join, alias

I joined 4 tables together.

How do I refer to it later on? Can I or do I need to name this table?

It is a simple inner joins:

```
select *
from table1 as 1
inner join table2 as 2 on x=y
inner join table3 as 3 on a=y
inner join table4 as 3 on z=a
```

Now when I refer to it later on in the code, how do I do that?

I tried to put everything (from table1 to z=a) in brackets and put "as tablename" behind it - it didnt work.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Once you provide a name to the table alias, you would refer to the alias in your joins as well as in your `SELECT` list:

```
select t1.x,
  t2.y,
  t3.y,
  t4.a
from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2 
  on t1.x = t2.y 
inner join table3 as t3 
  on t1.a = t3.y
inner join table4 as t4 
  on t1.z = t4.a
```

You will see that when I provided the table alias' above I provided a name that began with a letter and not a number.

Comment: i understand, but when i now refer to something from t3 to filter something out, will i still get every column from every table that i joined together? or will it return only the rows/colums of that specific table that i referred to?

Comment: @msa If you use a `WHERE` clause to filter data from `t3`, then you will only get the rows that match.

Comment: yes - but will this row contain all columns of the tables that i joined, or only columns belonging to t3?

Comment: @msa You have to add in your `SELECT` list the columns that you want to include from that table.